# Vertically center a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I have a ScrollView that I would like to vertically center. There are two requirements: when the ScrollView is small (one text line), that line should be in the center of screen. When the ScrollView is large (exceeds the screen size), it should function as a normal ScrollView. I can seemingly only get one or the other to work.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
   <Pressable style={flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}>
      <Pressable>
         <ScrollView />
      </Pressable>
   </Pressable>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the following:

```
const content = useMemo(() => <View onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => setContentHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height)}>{insert_anything}</View>, [insert_anything])

return <View onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => setParentHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
    {
        contentHeight >= parentHeight ?
        <ScrollView>{content}</ScrollView} :
        content
    }
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `alignSelf` property to `ScrollView` parent to center itself. [Here](https://snack.expo.io/@rohit376/graceful-orange) is a Snack for same.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
   <Pressable style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Pressable  style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '60%',
            alignSelf : 'center'
          }}>
         <ScrollView />
      </Pressable>
   </Pressable>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Sorry Rohit, there is no "justifySelf" property. Additionally, the Snack you provided is completely different than the code provided here, and does not vertically center.

Comment: @SteveC updated my answer, sorry it's `alignSelf` instead of `justifySelf` and in my Snack, I have the same structure as yours. I've just added text to show the results and has removed that now.

Comment: Sorry Rohit, this answer does not work, nor does your Snack. I appreciate your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Your ScrollView needs to have a fixed height.

```js
const CenteredScrollView = (props) => {
  // random text to render
  let randomText = [
    "Just some random stuff, ya know? Hopefully this manages to reach the point that it exceeds the screen size, ya know ? ",
    "Read on brother of another mother. ",
    "Read on sister of another mister. ",
    "Some words here. Hopefully this manages to reach the point that it exceeds the screen size, ya know ? ",
    "Some words there. Hopefully this manages to reach the point that it exceeds the screen size, ya know ? ",
    "Some words where? Hopefully this manages to reach the point that it exceeds the screen size, ya know ? ",
    "I really dont know what but some stuff has just happened. ",
    "How much text do I need to fill the screen size? ",
    ]
    // simulate ScrollView exceeding screen height
    for( let i = 0; i<5;i++)
      randomText = randomText.concat(randomText.reverse())
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1 }}>
      <Pressable style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor:'green' }}>
        <Pressable>
          <ScrollView
           {/*important to give ScrollView a height*/}  
           style={{backgroundColor:'pink',height:'50%'}}
          >
            {randomText.map((text,i)=><Text key={i}>{text}</Text>)}
          </ScrollView>
        </Pressable>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks PhantomSpooks, but a fixed height is not what I am looking for, because if the ScrollView is only a single line I still want that to be centered. I've clarified this in the question.